# HttpClient not sending POST parameters running out of ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application that is working as a data manager(React on FrontEnd) and queries REST API to get the data. I encountered a problem recently  where it is unable to send POST parameters when i run PostAsJsonAsync().

It actually does it once, but never after that.(until the REST server reboots, then it can do it once again)

what i do is this:(Client side ASP.NET Core)

```
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
                Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.0.2.135:80/apiEndpiont/");
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

Client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/users/login", new LoginCredentials("mylogin", "mypassword"));
```

On a server end I have the following: (REST API SERVER... using WebApi NOT AN ASP.NET Core)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Users/Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginCredentials auth)
{
   ....some code
   auth  - always stays "null", except for the first time of running a query
}
```

I also made a winForms app that uses the same tasting approach and it works every time, even in a same session where the other one doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure how you even got the code to compile unless `Object` here is a custom class you've created. If so, then the problem is very likely that you're colliding with `System.Object`. You should really not name your classes the same as any system classes, especially `Object`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt it is a custom object, i just corrected a question

Comment: I know of no good reason why it would only work once and then stop. However, you're using `HttpClient` wrong, so it's possible it could be an exhausted connections issue. `HttpClient` should be treated as a singleton for the most part. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1 for more info.

Comment: @AnKing Also make sure the `LoginCredentials` class has a paramterless constructor and that the properties are writable otherwise the model binder wont know how create and populate the model

Comment: You appear to be mixing frameworks as `IHttpActionResult ` is not asp.net-core.

Comment: @Nkosi This is a piece of server-end code that is a part of REST API, which is not an ASP.NET Core

Comment: @AnKing you tagged the question with asp.net core? Clarify what platform is being used and which code belongs to which platform.

Comment: @Nkosi, I've updated the question to clarify